# How to work with month function of vbscript with different local

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, vbscript

below is the code of VBScript,

```vb
FromDate=22/2/2013
ToDate=  1/3/2013
StartDateSerial = DateSerial(year(FromDate),month(FromDate), day(FromDate))
ToDateSerial = DateSerial(year(ToDate),month(toDate),day(ToDate))
```

in this date format is dd/mm/yyyy. but result of DateSerial is as below

```vb
StartDateSerial= 2/22/2013
ToDateSerieal= 1/3/2013
```

which mean for start date it converted to **mm/dd/yyyy** but for ToDateSerieal it converts to **dd/mm/yyyy**

I found this issue on **US lacal**.  But At **UK local** this is same for both.

Now when I try this with following values in FromDate and To Date

```vb
FromDate=2/22/2013
ToDate=  3/1/2013
```

I am passing FromDate and ToDate from JavaScript to vbscript.

Format is mm/dd/yyyy then it works fine on US lacal but not on UK local. Can any body tell me how can I fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, you pass d/m/y strings from Javascript to VBScript running with US locale which expects m/d/y date strings. If presented with a bad date string, VBScript tries to do the right thing and converts "22/2/2013" to a february date; "1/3/2013" is seen as a valid january date. UK locale understands d/m/y strings, "1/3/2013" is a march date.

To solve your problem - d/m/y date string input for all locales - use `a = Split("d/m/y", "/")` on the strings and `DateSerial(a[2], a[1], a[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you are working on the correct locale, you can use [SetLocale](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_setlocale.asp) to set the locale. For `dd/mm/yyyy` you can use `2057`, the `English UK` locale.

```
cl = GetLocale()

SetLocale(1033) ' US locale
wscript.echo FormatDateTime("1/3/2013",1)

SetLocale(2057) ' UK locale
wscript.echo FormatDateTime("1/3/2013",1)

' Set back the original locale
SetLocale(cl)

' Output:
' Thursday, January 03, 2013
' 01 March 2013
```